# How to get GrandTotal without shipping and tax in Magento

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I need to put the value of "Grand Total without shipping and tax" into a JavaScript on the success.phtml-page. To add the Grand Total i use the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->__('%s', $this->escapeHtml($this->getGrandTotal())) ?>
```

I was thinking about using getSubtotal instead, but that will not be correct in case of any Shopping Cart Price Rule being used. So I think the approach must be something like: "GrandTotal *minus* shipping *minus* tax"

But how can I add these parameters to the code above?

EDIT: About using getSubtotal... I would then need to know how to subtract any discount given by coupon, anyone know how to do this? I was thinking about something like this:

```
<?php echo $this->__('%s', Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal() - getDiscount()); ?>
```

...however "getDiscount()" should be something more correct..

Thanks
-Espen

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code in javascript

```
                                                      try {
                                                    var total_ship_tax = parseFloat(parseFloat(cart.shipping_amount) + parseFloat(cart.tax_amount)).toFixed(2);
                                                  }
                                                 catch(er) {
                                                    var total_ship_tax = 0; 
                                                }
                                                var total_amount =  parseFloat(parseFloat(cart.total_amount)+total_ship_tax).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I really didn't get it to work.. However I think my solution will be to do the calculation in the php-code.